# How to blend canvas to background with CSS?

Tags: css, canvas

I have this program that enables the user to draw. I want the canvas on which you are drawing on to be overlaid across the background.

This works in firefox, but not in chrome.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRBywo

This is the CSS that I tried to use to make it work:

```
body {

  background-image: url('http://previews.123rf.com/images/pyzata/pyzata1307/pyzata130700105/20855013-black-and-white-brick-abstract-texture-background-Stock-Photo.jpg');

  mix-blend-mode: normal;

}


canvas {

  mix-blend-mode: overlay;

}
```

Here is the P5JS code  for my canvas:

```
function setup() {

  c = createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  c.position(0, 0);

}

var oldX = 0;

var oldY = 0;


function draw() {


  if (mouseIsPressed) {

    strokeWeight(10);

    stroke(random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255));

    if (mouseX == oldX && mouseY == oldY) {

      point(mouseX, mouseY);

    } else {graffitiLine(mouseX, mouseY, oldX, oldY);

    }

  }

  oldX = mouseX;

  oldY = mouseY;

}

function graffitiLine(x0, y0, x1, y1) {

  line(x0, y0, x1, y1);

}

function disBetween(x0,y0,x1,y1){

  return sqrt(((x0-x1)*(x0-x1))+((y0-y1)*(y0-y1)));

}
```

and yes, I do know the image is ugly and watermarked I will change it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know p5 too much, but what you want is achievable without CSS at all :

- First, replace your p5 canvas with a Vanilla one.
- In your draw, proceed as usual on your p5 canvas (now off-screen), then draw your background-image, change the visible canvas `globalCompositeOperation` to `'multiply'`, fill a red rectangle, and finally draw your p5 canvas on the visible one, still with gCO set to `'overlay'`.

And voilà !

(Here I converted your sketch to an "instance-mode" one, but it may not be necessary...)

```js
var c, // your p5 canvas
  main, ctx, // the main canvas where we'll draw everything
  img; // the background-image

// we need to start the sketch in "instance mode" so we can have the background-image loaded
var s = function(p) {
  p.setup = function setup() {
    c = p.createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    c.position(0, 0);
    main = c.elt.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.replaceChild(main, c.elt); // replace the p5 canvas with our own
    ctx = main.getContext('2d');
  }

  p.draw = function draw() {

    if (p.mouseIsPressed) {
      p.strokeWeight(10);
      p.stroke(p.random(0, 255), p.random(0, 255), p.random(0, 255), p.random(0, 255));
      if (p.mouseX == p.oldX && p.mouseY == p.oldY) {
        p.point(p.mouseX, p.mouseY);
      } else {
        graffitiLine(p.mouseX, p.mouseY, p.oldX, p.oldY);
      }
    }
    p.oldX = p.mouseX;
    p.oldY = p.mouseY;

    drawToMain();
  }

  function drawToMain() {

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, main.width, main.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'overlay';
    ctx.drawImage(c.elt, 0, 0);

  }

  function graffitiLine(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
    p.line(x0, y0, x1, y1);
  }
};

function init() {
  var myp5 = new p5(s);
}

img = new Image();
img.onload = init;
img.src = "http://previews.123rf.com/images/pyzata/pyzata1307/pyzata130700105/20855013-black-and-white-brick-abstract-texture-background-Stock-Photo.jpg"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.0/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
```

Ps : I don't know why the CSS doesn't work on chrome, maybe you should open an issue in there bugzilla.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
body{
        background: url('http://previews.123rf.com/images/pyzata/pyzata1307/pyzata130700105/20855013-black-and-white-brick-abstract-texture-background-Stock-Photo.jpg') red;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

It seems to work in your codepen snippet in Chrome.

**EDIT:**

I misunderstood the question. Here's a plain HTML5 canvas fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hrivas/t2204vxh/--I don't know enough P5JS yet.

Basically, you need to draw the image and blend it with the desired background color, and when it's time to draw, you change the blend mode (there are several to pick from):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

img.src = 'http://previews.123rf.com/images/pyzata/pyzata1307/pyzata130700105/20855013-black-and-white-brick-abstract-texture-background-Stock-Photo.jpg';

// compose the image and the background when the image is loaded
img.onload = function () {
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

document.onmousemove = function() {
  var x = event.offsetX;
  var y = event.offsetY;
  
  // grafitti brush
  var r = 0;//parseInt(255 * Math.random());
  var g = 0;//parseInt(255 * Math.random());
  var b = parseInt(255 * Math.random());
  var a = Math.random();
  
  context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ", " + a;
  context.globalCompositeOperation = "lighten";
    
  context.moveTo(x, y);
  context.arc(x, y, 7, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    
  context.fill();
}
```

Other than that, turning off one or two color channels creates the varying intensity effect.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I think you missed the question, here is a fixed codepen of OP's issue with chrome (compare it with FF) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBmOgd

Comment: I see, he wants to blend the background image with the drawings. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Then it becomes just a copy of my answer, doesn'it?

Comment: Well it seems OP wants to use p5, also, you should remember to call ctx.beginPath at each new path drawings, otherwise you are fillling with your new color all the previously drawn arcs, which will produce ugly artifacts at the end and not the correct one color per arc feature that OP has in his code.

Comment: Fair enough. I've removed the path on v1 of the fiddle--left overs from some previous line drawing attempts. Thanks!